# How can I suppress the output due to a SIGSEGV or a SIGFPE in a Fortran 90 program?

Tags: bash, fortran, segmentation-fault

I have a bash script that runs a simulation program written in Fortran 90, and all output is redirected to a file. If the program finishes without problems, I set a success parameter. The code looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
echo -n "Running program..."
./sim_program >& file && success="true"
if [ $success ]; then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "NOT OK"
fi
...
```

The output to screen should be either "Running program... OK" or "Running program... NOT OK". In some cases, the simulation program will crash with a floating point exception or a segmentation fault, and the corresponding signals are sent (SIGSEGV / SIGFPE). The output may then look something like this:

```
:~>execute_script
Running program.../path/to/script: line 232: 15350 Floating Point Exception ./sim_program >& file && success="true"
NOT OK
```

How can I suppress the error output due to the SIGFPE or SIGSEGV such that I get

```
:~>execute_script
Running program... NOT OK
```

even when there is such an error? I have looked into using trap, e.g.

```
trap "" SIGSEGV SIGFPE
./sim_program >& file && success="true"
trap SIGSEGB SIGFPE
```

but then I still get something like

```
:~>execute_script
Running program... Floating Point Exception
NOT OK
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message is probably going to stderr.

Try putting this at the start of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2> /dev/null
```

and anything send to stderr will go to the null device rather than your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error message is written on stderr. You need to redirect it to /dev/null.

./sim_program 2>/dev/null