# Check for stdout or stderr

Tags: bash, shell, segmentation-fault, stdout, stderr

One of the binaries which I am using in my shell script is causing a segmentation fault (RETURN VALUE: 139)

And even though, I am redirecting both stdout and stderr to a logfile, the Segmentation Fault error messages is displayed in the terminal when I am running the shell script.

Is it possible to redirect this message from Segfault to a logfile ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am answering my own question.. :) 
I found the answer here 
[How can I suppress the output due to a SIGSEGV or a SIGFPE in a Fortran 90 program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416351/how-can-i-suppress-the-output-due-to-a-sigsegv-or-a-sigfpe-in-a-fortran-90-progra/416433)

The trick is to add

```
`exec 2> filename`
```

in the shell script.

This will redirect all the messages from the shell to a log file

Answer (score 2):

The Segmentation Fault message you see is printed by the shell that is running your program. This behavior varies from shell to shell, so a few things you could try (if you insist on getting the segmentation fault message into your logs from shell-redirects).

```
# Have sh invoke your program, and redirect output from both sh and your program into logfile
sh -c "program arguments more arguments" >logfile 2>&1
# Force bash to not just exec your program (/bin/true part), and redirect output
# from both bash and your program into logfile
bash -c "/bin/true; program arguments more arguments" >logfile 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
./program &> logfile
```

there are various exampls on I/O redirection [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), have a look

You  can take a look at this [discussion](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2004-12/0135.html) as well

Comment: Well, It ddid not work, 
here is my code which is causing problem :

"$DECODER" -if $input_file -of $output_file >> $log_file 2>&1 

here is the output when Segfault is caused : 

./decode.sh: line 292: 15475 Segmentation fault "$DECODER" $IF input..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988279/bash-redirecting-of-stdoutput-and-stderror-does-not-catch-all-output

I am looking at a similar approach.. but within a shell script

Comment: you can see http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2004-12/0135.html for a discussion

Comment: I got the solution here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416351/how-can-i-suppress-the-output-due-to-a-sigsegv-or-a-sigfpe-in-a-fortran-90-progra/416433

The trick is to add exec 2> <filename>
Thanks again
krian